# How to get distance from bottom of screen to a particular widget in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I need to calculate the distance from the bottom of a screen to a container.Is it possible to calculate distance from bottom of a screen to Container and distance from top of a screen to container in separately?

I got the distance from top like this,

```
 RenderBox box = keyGlobal.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
              Offset position = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero); //this is global position
              double y = position.dy;
```

Is it possible to get distance from bottom?

Comment: Maybe something like `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - (box.size.height + position.dy)`